# Generate email to file without sending

Tags: php, email

I want to generate an email using the `mail()` function:

```
<?php
$to      = 'nobody@example.com';
$subject = 'the subject';
$message = 'hello';
$headers = 'From: webmaster@example.com' . "\r\n" .
    'Reply-To: webmaster@example.com' . "\r\n" .
    'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();

// instead of sending mail, out put to file
mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);
?>
```

But instead of having it actually send the email, I want it to output the email to file with all of the headers etc. as a mail server would see it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We use the [Zend_Mail](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.mail.html) library and have different transports for destination (SMTP, STDOUT, file, etc.). Just in case that's an option, here's some information on Zend_Mail [transports](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.mail.different-transports.html).

Comment: This pushed me in the right direction. Since I use cake, I was able to use the 'debug' output method on the email component and pull the email information from the session. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

With SwiftMailer you can use plugin: http://swiftmailer.org/wikidocs/v3/plugindev/sendevent

Comment: This looks interesting. Thanks for the suggestion. I will review this in a little more depth.